# Проблема со сборкой в asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, wcf

Пишу приложение с Asp.net и wcf service, после запуска выдает ошибку
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.

Что может быть не так?